# How to evaluate a HTML DOM object (like "document") in RubyRacer

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dom

RubyRacer allows me to easily execute javascript code within a ruby environment, like so:

```
cxt = V8::Context.new
wanted_output = cxt.eval(whatever_javascipt_code)
```

How does one have to do it when objects like "document" are involved, like for example in the follwing code snippet?
(In other words, how can I generate the output of "document.write" in this case?)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  A="some_string";
  B="some_other_string";
  C="";

  for(j=0;j<B.length;j++){
    C+=A.charAt(B.charCodeAt(j)-48);
  }document.write(C);
</script>
```

Simply evaluating the script above would result in the error message:

```
"V8::JSError: document is not defined"
```

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Comment: That's the first I heard of this gem and it sounds interesting. Too bad it doesn't install on windows :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the variable 'script' contains the javascript code mentioned above:

```
cxt = V8::Context.new
script.insert(0, "output=''")

document_write_count = script.scan('document.write(').count
remaining = script
document_write_count.times do |i|
  document_write_clause_content = remaining.partition('document.write(')[2].partition(')')[0]
  document_write_clause = "document.write(#{document_write_clause_content})"
  document_write_clause_replacement = "output+=#{document_write_clause_content}"
  script.gsub!(document_write_clause, document_write_clause_replacement)
  remaining = remaining.rpartition(document_write_clause_replacement)[2]
end

script.insert(-1, "output;")

wanted_output = cxt.eval("#{script}")
```